# matching phone numbers from text in a file

Tags: regex, perl

I need help with my Perl code.

I want to search a file and read it line by line and if the parent of a phone number matches it must print that line to another file.

I am able to match a string but not sure : How to match a format/pattern of a phone number 
Phone numbers can be different. I just want to follow the format of phone number match.

Example of Number can be  xx-xxx-xxxx

This is my code take a look

```
#!//usr/bin/perl

# Saving The Aurgument Values To Local Variables Sent from the Command line

$source         = $ARGV[0];
$pattren        = $ARGV[1];
$destination        = $ARGV[2];

$matches        = 0;


# Using open function to open the file and the pointer will be save to variable $fh
# die condition used with a message is the file name give from the command line could
# doesn't exsist

open($sr, '<', $source) or die "Could not open file $source ";
open($ds, '>', $destination);

# Using While loop condition as long as we are getting data per line.

while ($line = <$sr>){ #While reading one line at a time from the log....

  if ($line =~ m/$pattren/i) {   
        #Printing the Mached line Content Of the source File to the destination the File.
        print $ds $line;
        $matches++;
  }
}

close $ds;
close $sr;

print "\n";
print "Macthes Found = ". $matches. "\n";
print "Reading from File    = " . $source . "\n";
print "Writing it to File   = " . $destination . "\n";



print "\n";

# End of file extract
```

Comment: Though a side note, you seem to be writing Perl 4 style Perl =). `use strict; use warnings` and declare variables with scope using `my`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>> Example of Number can be xx-xxx-xxxx
```

Then your regex could be

```
\b\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}\b
```

So run your perl script with following command

```
test.pl infile '\b\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}\b' outfile
```

Comment: $pattren = 12-345-6789, so reading from file if the pattern matches in any line it should print that line , i hope i am making sense :(

Comment: @HaiderRehman I didn't get you. Does this number can be anywhere in the line? on in that line there is just a number? could you post sample input file?

Comment: @HaiderRehman the code you have takes any regex pattern an matches it. So all you have to do it : `perl yourcode.pl infile.txt '^\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$' outfile.txt ` . And outfile has all numbers that match the pattern you want.

Comment: @jkshah Ok this is content in the text file. 

This is the content file for 12-345-6789
which is to read file and get the
99-545-6289 asda sdadsaf

so i want to search for phone numbers and if there patren matches it should print that line

Comment: @HaiderRehman you don't actually have to change the variable. Leave you code as it is. Just run the command in my above comment.

Comment: ./extract 'source.txt' '^\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$' 'destination.txt'

Macthes Found = 0
Reading from File    = source.txt
Writing it to File   = destination.txt

Comment: @HaiderRehman it works perfectly for me. Can you double check your source?

Comment: @gideon it seems line also contains some other text with number. replaced `^` and `$` with `\b`

Comment: @jkshah good thinking :) The OP should show his input file though.

Comment: Note there's a giant caveat that this regexp will only extract one kind of phone numbers, which may be ok for your task, but if you want to support multiple phone number notations, a Regexp::Common library would be helpful